# mysqli select not returning right number of records

Tags: php, mysqli, left-join

I have this select query and all records in customers table that has a record in transactions table is returning fine but it does not return all newly added records from customers table that has no records on transactions table but only 1.

I have tried the statement to be executed in SQL in PHPMyAdmin and it is perfectly fine, returns all the records.

What is wrong with the script? How come its not returning all the records in customers table that has no record in transactions table but only 1.

```
$q ="SELECT cust.*, 
            COALESCE(SUM(p.transactions_amount), 0) AS total 
       FROM customers cust 
  LEFT JOIN transactions p 
         ON p.transactions_customer_id = cust.customer_id 
   GROUP BY cust.customer_id
   ORDER BY cust.customer_id DESC";

$query = mysqli_prepare($connection,$q); 
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($query))
{
    // execute query only
    if($return === false)
    {
        mysqli_close($connection); 
        return true;
    }
    //return values
    else
    {
        $result = array();    
        $meta = $query->result_metadata();
        while ($field = $meta->fetch_field())
        {
            $params[] = &$row[$field->name];
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($query, 'bind_result'), $params);
        while ($query->fetch())
        {
            var_dump($row);
            $temp = array();
            foreach($row as $key => $val)
            {
                $temp[$key] = $val;
            } 
            $result[] = $temp;
        }

        $meta->free();
        $query->close(); 
        return $result;                
    }
}
else
{
    mysqli_close($connection); 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: try the most basic [fetching](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and debug, compare it to your prepared statement fetching and find out

Answer (score 0):

I got it all working, I was just calling the wrong function for the display, silly me. the above code is working